# 502 Bad Gateway error while using apache2 with terraform deployment on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, frontend, apache2

In order to support redirecting our requests, we decided to copy over the apache2 configuration here in a terraform repository where it was earlier running with nginx. But after switching over and running `apache2-foreground`, we get a bad gateway error.

These are the contents of our webapp docker file:

```
FROM node:latest AS build
WORKDIR /build
COPY --chown=node:node . /build
COPY --chown=node:node ./webapp.env /build/.env
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
USER node

FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl wget apache2 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY ./000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY ./ports.conf /etc/apache2/ports.conf
COPY ./apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY --from=build /build/build/ /var/www/html/cadis
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "apache2-foreground" ]
```

This was a critical piece of config from the `000-default.conf` file which solved the problem with redirects on our AWS sandbox, which we also included here:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cadis

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    <Directory /var/www/html/cadis>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

But when we try to access the website, it shows:

[502 backend error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYxNJ.png)

To be clear, our traffic for the website does still get routed through nginx. It forwards the request to either the apache2 server / backend server.

Can anyone help understand whether we're missing anything in terms of configuration?

We need this in order for redirects and other actions ex: refreshing a page to work. This is the URL for our website -

[website](https://dev.cadis-ezi.com/)

Comment: There isn't really anything with redirects that apache can do that nginx cannot. Your posted config does not contain any redirects, it only serves static html. Your posted error is occuring before apache would be hit.

Comment: Update: We were able to solve the issue by copying specific relevant sections from the apache2 configuration to work in tandem with nginx minus running the apache2 server.